# modalbox opening in 403 page

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using a custom modalbox and the code for generating it is as follows :

```
  function openConfig1(html,hidden,type)
    {
        html = html.substring(0, html.length-7)+hidden+'</form>';
        if(type=='prod' && document.getElementById('popup-title'))
            document.getElementById('popup-title').textContent = 'Upgrade / Downgrade Product ';
        else if(type=='conf' && document.getElementById('popup-title'))
            document.getElementById('popup-title').textContent = 'Upgrade / Downgrade Configurable Option';

        document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML =html;
        document.getElementById('popup-submit').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('popup_submit_btn').setAttribute('class','btn10 pop_submit');
        document.forms.popup_form.style.display='none';
        initCustomForms();
        $.abc = $('#lightbox').simplebox();
        $.abc.init($('#lightbox'),{});
        $.abc.toPrepare('#lightbox');
    }
```

My issue is theat when the 'html' contains large contents, and if I do middle click on mouse, it is showing a 403 with all the html in it.  I am attahing a screenshot for verifications. This issue is only in Firefox in Linux . It is working perfectly and opening the modalbox in all other browsers and platforms.

[image]

Comment: Does your console give you any other errors?

Comment: Nothing other than NetworkError: 403 Forbidden.